# What's an IK Setup that Allows Hands to Stay Planted?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, inverse-kinematics

After some months of learning Blender, I've reached another roadblock. I looked up an IK setup for feet and legs, which works great with no complaints. I then started work on an animation involving the hands, where one rests on a wall, and that's when my lack of knowledge flared back up. I thought another, simple IK setup would've worked, but instead of the hand resting on the wall like the feet rest on the floor, the hand rotates with the arm whenever the root or the body moves. The idea is the person is shifting their weight while the hand is on the wall, but it doesn't look good with the hand moving about as it is.

I made a basic recreation of the armature. It doesn't work *exactly* as the original, so ignoring the minor mistakes with the rig, the point is that the foot stays planted while the hand doesn't.

[image: One of the example armatures. The hand is correctly placed on the "wall".]

After moving the hips, the hand is now clipping into the wall.

[image: The same example armature, the hand now clipping after the hips moved.]

I'm aware the problem is that the lower part of the bone is attached to the arm instead of the IK control bone, but after trying some possible solutions, like using Pole Targets, attempting to replicate the foot setup on the hand, and some variations of those, it either continues to stay attached or isn't attached at all, the ladder also not being preferred.

Any amount of insight into a solution would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the IK constraint on the hand bone, with chain lenght of 3 (hand, lower arm, upper arm), while you should set it on the lower arm bone, targeting the hand, with lenght 2. In this way, animating the hand will have the arm naturally follow, while if the hand is still and the body moves, arm bones move but the hand stays still.